# How do I scan an image directly on a webpage with an OCR?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, ocr

What i'm basically trying to do is going on a webpage with selenium and trying to get past a **captcha** that has been done very poorly. I should mention I'm using **python** with **selenium 4** to scrape said webpage.

In short, this captcha simply displays some numbers that change along with their colors every time I fail to do the captcha and that need to be written in a box in order to pass it, which seems like an extremeley simple thing to get by. I'll attach one of them
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhT3U.png), and an example of a second one after i failed the captcha [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpBu2.png).

All i need in a good **OCR** that manages to read an image directly on the webpage without needing to download it, and store this value to later input it into an input box. Is there any tool that can help me do just that? I looked a little bit online and I couldn't seem to find anything like this. Can anyone suggest me the right library for this and, if you really could, how to read this image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a screenshot in Selenium: [https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html#:~:text=Taking%20Screenshot%20in%20Selenium%20is,Copy%20file%20to%20Desired%20Location](https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html#:%7E:text=Taking%20Screenshot%20in%20Selenium%20is,Copy%20file%20to%20Desired%20Location)

And then run it through an OCR: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: Not a bad solution, but if there was anything simpler than taking the screenshot (as from what you showed me its not easy at all, and taking a screenshot would mean that that i would need to delete the image every time, something that kind of defeats the purpose of automating this process in the first place). If there was a better approach, I would prefer it, but i'll go with this one if there isn't a better way. Still, even if not what I'm looking for, an option for sure. So thank you!

Comment: Well, you can try OpenCV with Selenium for digit detection, but I fear it's going to be even more complicated and you may still need to save images/screenshots to accomplish your task.